# Use Chrome's Presentation Mode (if there is such a thing) on Android Tablet

Tags: android, google-chrome, tablet

Chrome for Android has the fullscreen mode, which is however, still have bars on the top and the bottom. I want to completely cover the screen with the chrome app view. Is there anyways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

These bars are connected to the Android running on your device, not chrome itself. You should look in device settings.